# LinkedIn JavaScript API - Access to people denied

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the LinkedIn JavaScript API from this webpage [JSAPI Tutorial: People Search](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_search/) but when I try it the json response I receive is this:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to people search denied.",
  "requestId": "JEDHDU95PC",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1354094114382
}
```

This is my code which is identical to their code except I changed the api key to the one associated with my localhost environment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: my_key
    authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData() {
        IN.API.PeopleSearch()
         .fields("firstName", "lastName", "distance", "publicProfileUrl", "pictureUrl")
         .params({ "keywords": "python", "count": 10, "sort": "distance" })
         .result(function (result) {
             profHTML = "<h4>People search results for keyword 'python':</h4>";
             for (var index in result.people.values) {
                 profile = result.people.values[index]
                 if (profile.pictureUrl) {
                     profHTML += "<p><a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
                     profHTML += "<img class=img_border height=30 align=\"left\" src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\"></a>";
                     profHTML += "<p>" + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + " (" + profile.distance + ")</p>";
                 }
             }
             $("#search").html(profHTML);
         });
    }
</script>

<div id="search">
    </div>
    <script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
```

The weird thing is that [JSAPI Tutorial: Authenticating a User using JSAPI](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_authentication/) works. I can authenticate my key and return data but it doesn't work for search and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar problem. You need to apply for "Vetted API Access Request". 
Go to https://help.linkedin.com/app/api-dvr and fill this form for grant people search API.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try adding:
scope: r_network
in the first script block.

Comment: r_network option not working, you need to make an request to linked in via vetted API Access form when they approved then you can search further data. Currently this limitation on job and people search API.

Answer (score 0):

Do not expect LinkedIn to respond to your vetted API access unless you are doing something significant and worth interest of LinkedIn and not directly in competition to them.
Typically if you are one of the unfortunate folks who have started after Sep-2013, all your new API keys will never work with vetted APIs.